# User Attribute Errors on github3.py Login

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-api, github3.py

Recently had a fun project idea and wanted to utilize the GitHub API, so I searched around for a Python wrapper. On the GitHub libraries page I found [github3.py](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py)

After looking at their [docs](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'GitHub' object has no attribute 'me'`, from this code example

```
from github3 import login

gh = login('sigmavirus24', password='<password>')

sigmavirus24 = gh.me()
# <User [sigmavirus24:Ian Cordasco]>

print(sigmavirus24.name)
# Ian Cordasco
print(sigmavirus24.login)
# sigmavirus24
print(sigmavirus24.followers_count)
# 4`
```

Is there something I'm missing from the documentation? Or have the docs just not been updated?

How do I fix this problem? I tried running `dir(gh)` to view attributes of the login object, but that's not telling me much, and have tried using `Python 2.7.11`, and `Python 3.4.3`.

Comment: Does importing the Github class fix your issue? First line should read `from github3 import login, Github`.

Comment: @mech OP isn't using the `Github` class in their code, so importing it won't do anything.

Comment: @mech Importing `GitHub`, doesn't do anything.

Comment: Nevermind then, I misread some of the docs while reading over them. Thanks for checking!

Comment: What is the output of `import github3; print(github3.__version__)`?

Comment: @MattDMo Version is 0.9.5...Wait...hmm looking at the GitHub page, most recent version looks like 0.9.3...? How is that possible? Docs aren't updated maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you linked to in your question is for version 1.0.0a3, whereas you are running 0.9.5. If you look at the same code snippet in the [0.9.5 docs](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.5/), you'll see the syntax is slightly different:

```
from github3 import login

gh = login('sigmavirus24', password='<password>')

sigmavirus24 = gh.user()
#                 ^^^^ instead of me()
```

If you want to use the latest version, download and install from the [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/github3.py/1.0.0a3#downloads). Or, if you want to continue using your current version, just follow the 0.9.5 docs I linked to above.

Also, one other hint - to list the methods and attributes available for a particular object, use `dir(objectname)` instead of `help()`.

Comment: Oops. Just edited my question. I did in fact use `dir()`. Hmm... Don't know how I missed that small issue. Thanks Matt!